# Joomla 3.6.5 & 3.7.0 Strange User Session Behavior

Tags: user, access, bugs

Just today, an issue arised with a Joomla 3.6.5 installation I have.

A user was seeing other connected users' details. Something went wrong with the session table (I suppose, because I checked and there were more records than I expected) and all of a sudden, **this user was able to see and edit other user data, but only in specific pages**.

It looked as if it went back and forth between this user's and another user's session.

Then I updated to Joomla 3.7.0 and another issue came up: Some menu items are "external URLs" which I use as text separators, due to some issues I had with iPads. Their external URL is just a hash (#), to work as a text separator, thus pointing to my home page.
When someone clicks on that link, they are taken back to the home page and **the page looks as if they were logged-out**, and a prompt to login is back there. If you click on it, nothing happens and you have to use a menu item to navigate back to the site, where **you find out that you are still logged-in**.

The user information kept in this site is very sensitive, and suddenly my users see each other's data!
Any help is desperately appreciated.

Comment: What hosting is it on?  I had a client several months back with a site on Network Solutions with some crazy cache/sessions problems.  Never did figure out cause and there were zero issues when I cloned to my server.  Might try cloning to another server to rule that out.

Comment: It's on Justhost. Just downloaded a backup with Akeeba Backup and absolutely no issue on my localhost. I made another backup from localhost and will re-upload, and post as soon as I see if the issue continues.

Comment: The issue only happens on my host. The website completely works on localhost. I asked the host and they claim it is not their issue.

Comment: I found out that, when I open Chrome Developer Tools and make sure that Disable Cache is enabled, the page works normally. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something is caching data for authenticated users when it shouldn't be.  Generally within the core Joomla extensions, they will only serve cached data to guest users.

Comment: Thank you for posting. This is exactly the problem. I contacted my host and finally they accepted the fact that they have some caching system called "Varnish". Do you have any clue on how to disable that?

Comment: You will need to talk with your host about it.  Generally Varnish isn't a bad thing but it has to be configured correctly.

Comment: Thank you Michael. Your answer was very helpful. I have also posted the solution, below.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of searching, my host pointed out the fact that they use Varnish, which is a cache system, incompatible with Joomla, by default. They didn't seem eager to edit its settings, but they told me to add the following to my `.htaccess` file.

```
Header add "disablevcache" "true"
```

After doing so, the issue was resolved within 24 to 36 hours.